# How do Linux permissions work when a process is running as a specific group?

Tags: linux, permissions, process, chroot, chmod

This is something I haven't been able to find much info on so any help would be appreciated.

My understanding is thus. Take the following file:

```
-rw-r-----  1 root        adm   69524 May 21 17:31 debug.1
```

The user `phil` cannot access this file:

```
phil@server:/var/log$ head -n 1 debug.1
cat: debug.1: Permission denied
```

If `phil` is added to the `adm` group, it can:

```
root@server:~# adduser phil adm
Adding user `phil' to group `adm' ...
Adding user phil to group adm
Done.
phil@server:/var/log$ head -n 1 debug.1
May 21 11:23:15 server kernel: [    0.000000] DMI: QEMU Standard PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996), BIOS rel-1.7.5.1-0-g8936dbb-20141113_115728-nilsson.home.kraxel.org 04/01/2014
```

If, however, a process is started whilst explicitly setting the `user:group` to `phil:phil` it cannot read the file. Process started like this:

```
nice -n 19 chroot --userspec phil:phil / sh -c "process"
```

If the process is started as `phil:adm`, it can read the file:

```
nice -n 19 chroot --userspec phil:adm / sh -c "process"
```

So the question really is:

What is special about running a process with a specific user/group combo that prevents the process being able to access files owned by supplementary groups of that user and is there any way around this?

Comment: Note the shell has nothing to do with it: Permissions are not processed by the shell. If they where you could gain root by writing a new shell.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A process is run with a uid ang a gid. Both have permissions assigned to them. You could call chroot with a userspec of a user and group, where actually the user is not in that group. The process would then executed with the users uid and the given groups gid.

See an example. I have a user called `user`, and he is in the group `student`:

```
root@host:~$ id user
uid=10298(user) gid=20002(student) groups=20002(student)
```

I have a file as follows:

```
root@host:~$ ls -l file
-rw-r----- 1 root root 9 Mai 29 13:39 file
```

He cannot read it:

```
user@host:~$ cat file
cat: file: Permission denied
```

Now, I can execte the `cat` process in the context of the user `user` AND the group `root`. Now, the cat process has the necessary permissions:

```
root@host:~$ chroot --userspec user:root / sh -c "cat file"
file contents
```

Its interesting to see what `id` says:

```
root@host:~$ chroot --userspec user:root / sh -c "id"
uid=10298(user) gid=0(root) groups=20002(student),0(root)
```

Hm, but the user `user` is not in that group (`root`). Where does `id` get its informations from? If called without argument, `id` uses the system calls, [`getuid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getuid), [`getgid()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/getgid) and [`getgroups()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setgroups.2.html). So the process context of `id` itself is printed. That context we have altered with `--userspec`.

When called with an argument, `id` just determines the group assignments of the user:

```
root@host:~$ chroot --userspec user:root / sh -c "id user"
uid=10298(user) gid=20002(student) groups=20002(student)
```

**To your question:**

> What is special about running a process with a specific user/group
>   combo that prevents the process being able to access files owned by
>   supplementary groups of that user and is there any way around this?

You can set the security process context that is needed to solve whatever task the process needs to do. **Every** process has a uid and gid set under which he runs. Normally the process "takes" the calling users uid and gid as his context. With "takes" I means the kernel does, otherwise it would be a security problem.

So, it's actually not the user, that has no permissions to read the file, its the process' permissions (`cat`). But the process runs with the uid/gid of the calling user.

So you don't have to be in a specific group for a process to run with your uid and the gid of that group.

Comment: A process normally has only the credentials of the primary group.  It can gain acess to the credentials of the secondary groups the `EUID` is part of by calling `initgroups(3)`.  However, `initgroups(3)` is a relatively expensive operation, since it needs to enumerate all groups.  For this reason, processes only call `initgroups(3)` if they have a specific reason to do it.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `--userspec` option on `chroot` specifies the user and a single group to use when running the `chroot`. To define supplementary groups you need to use the `--groups` option as well.

By default processes inherit the primary and supplementary groups of the user running them, but by using `--userspec` you're telling `chmod` to override that using the single group specified.

Detailed documentation of permissions in Linux is available in the [`credentials(7)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) manpage.

Answer (score 4):

When you log into Linux, the login process¹ -after verifying you can log in as *phil*- gets the uid of phil and the groups it belongs to, setting those as a process which is then started as your shell. *The uid, gid and supplemental groups are a property of the process.*

Any later program started after that, is a descendant of that shell, and simply receives a copy of those credentials.* This explains why changing the rights of the user doesn't affect the running processes. The changes will be picked up on next login, however.

* The exception are programs whose setuid or setgid bits are set, which will have a different *effective user id*. This is used for instance in [su(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/su.1.html) so it can run with `root` privileges even when executed by `phil`.

After you added `phil` to the `adm` group, he could run `su phil`, and `su` will -running as root- verify that he indeed provides phil's password and then land him into a shell with the uid, gid and supplemental groups phil belongs to. And as this is done after adding the user to the group, that shell would already be in the `adm` group.

I don't consider chroot(1) the most suited program for *running as a different user*, but it certainly gets the work done. The parameter `--userspec phil:phil` makes it run with the uid of `phil` and the gid of `phil`. No additional groups are set (for that you would provide `--groups`). Thus, the children process is not in the `adm` group.

A more normal way for running your process as phil would be `su phil -c "process"`. As `su` loads the uid, gid and supplemental groups from the user database information, `process` will have the same credentials the user currently has.

¹ This may be [login(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/login.1.html), sshd, su, gdb or other programs. Also, it is likely being managed through pam modules.