# Is there a way to give different permissions to different processes that are called from the same user?

Tags: files, permissions, filesystems, process, directory

I want to be able to have a r,w,x type permission given to specific processes and not to users. Any document I find shows that processes get the same permissions as the user calling it, but I want different processes to have different permissions even on the same user.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You can make your processes setuid or setgid to another user or group. However, please note that you are working against the very basic principles of the operating system.

Comment: @AlexP The following link shows that that won't work though. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/206289/how-do-linux-permissions-work-when-a-process-is-running-as-a-specific-group

Comment: @AlexP And even if it did work, I want a process to be able to access fileA but not fileB for the same user. If I change the setuid for the process, even if a user created fileA, he may not be able to access it anymore using that said process.

Comment: Setuid and setgid bits absolutely do work. The link provided discusses a well known behavior of GNU/Linux systems.

Comment: Access rights are determined by the effective user id and effective group id of a process. Normally a process gets its EUID and EGID from the invoking process, but it may also take them from the owner or group of the image which is `exec`'d, if the appropriate bits are set in the access mode of the image. Use `man 7 credentials` for more details.